# Show that $f'$ is unbounded on $(0,1]$ but that $f$ is nevertheless uniformly continuous on $(0,1].$

Tags: real-analysis

The question is this. Let $f(x) = \sqrt{x}, \forall x \geq 0.$ Show that $f'$ is unbounded on $(0,1]$ but that $f$ is nevertheless uniformly continuous on $(0,1].$ Compare with Theorem 19.6.

The theorem 19.6 is this.

**Theorem :** Let $f$ be a continuous function on an interval $I$ [$I$ may be bounded or unbounded.] Let $I'$ be the interval obtained by removing from $I$ any endpoints that happen to be in $I.$ If $f$ is differentiable on $I'$ and if $f'$ is bounded on $I',$ then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $I.$

Can anyone explain this??

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is continuous, $[0, 1]$ is compact. $f'$ has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Any continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the second part is: $p\to q$ is not equivalent to $q\to p$.

In this case $p$ denotes "$f'$ is bounded" and $q$ denotes "$f$ is uniformly continuous".  The theorem proves that $p\to q$; the example shows that $q\to p$ is false.